# SonarQube Code Coverage do not provide a correct value

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, sonarqube

I am new to SonarQube and I need to analyze my Java Spring MVC code with it. I add one Unit test but SonarQube analysis do not capture the unit test added. Following is my code line to test.

```
    @Autowired
    private InvoiceRepository repository;

    public Invoice  create(Invoice entity){
        entity.setInvoiceId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        return repository.insert(entity);
    }
```

Following is the Unit test I wrote using Junit.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Invoice obj = mapper.readValue(invoiceJson, Invoice.class);

    InvoiceRepository dataServiceMock = mock(InvoiceRepository.class);
    when(dataServiceMock.insert(invTest1)).thenReturn(new  Invoice("ABC", "1", "INV-1", today, "FLTR-123", "Test Service Provider", null, "Cus Mane", "077777777", "06555555",
        null, null, true, null, null, "BC", null, "43", true, null, null));
    InvoiceService service = new InvoiceService();
    Invoice invTemp = service.create(obj);

    assertEquals(invTest1.getInvoiceId(), invTemp.getInvoiceId());
```

I updated the `pom.xml` file with relevant packages as well(`org.springframework.boot` and `org.jacoco`)

The SonarQube report showing the following error.

[image]

The Red line in the analysis report shows "Not covered by Tests".

It would be great if someone can help me to fix this issue.

I executed the analysis using commandline using

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
```

Comment: Have you build the project after changes?

Comment: Gaurav Srivastav: I just used the maven builder

Comment: Jacco report showing correct value?

Comment: Jacco report showing correct value? No

Comment: Please add `jacoco-maven-plugin` configuration.